# creating a customer login function using the prestashop webservice

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, password-protection

I'm currently working on an application that makes use of the prestashop webservice. This means that the application i'm building is an extension of an existing prestashop application. The connection between both applications is through the [prestashop webservice](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service)

Currently i'm trying to create a login script for the`customers`. The email and password are obtained from the database through the webservice and i'm able to filter the inputs with the existing row's. So when filling in login@test.com. The filter will only obtain the row with that email address.

The problem i'm having is with the password. Prestashop uses a `_COOKIE_KEY_` together with an`md5()` to encrypt passwords. See this link for more information: [link](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Cookies)

So i've been trying some different things for a while to check the inputted password with the customers password but i haven't found the solution yet.

Take a look at the code below:

```
<?php

require_once('./PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

/**
 * get information from PrestaShop
 */

$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($url, $key, $debug);

define('_COOKIE_KEY_', '...');
$email = "login@test.nl";
define('password', "test");
$md5passwd = md5(_COOKIE_KEY_ . password);

$opt = array(
    "resource" => "customers",
    "display" => "[email , passwd]",
    "filter[email]" => "$email"
);

$optPass = array(
    "resource" => "customers",
    "display" => "[email]",
    "filter[email]" => "$email",
    "filter[passwd]" => "$md5passwd"
);

$jsonPass = ($webService->get( $optPass ));

//json encode it
$jsonPasswd = json_encode($jsonPass);

echo($jsonPasswd);


if(password_verify($md5passwd, $jsonPasswd)) {
    echo "password is valid";
} else {
    echo "password is not valid";
}

$jsonUrl = ($webService->get( $opt ));

//json encode it
$json = json_encode($jsonUrl);

echo($json);
```

As you can see i've been trying out things like the `password_verify` and the `md5()` but i can't quite get it. So is there anyone who has done this or who knows how to create a correct login script on the prestashop webservice?

**Update -- 12/1/2017**
So after doing some research i've come up with a new way of checking the user input. First the code checks the email and if it's true it will continue with checking the password input. But the problem i'm having is with the password and the password encryption of prestashop. I'm not able to compare the two hashes together. The first hash would be the hash from the database were the second hash is the user input password. The input would need a `hash()` function from prestashop. But i can't quite get to the right hash sequence of prestashop.

I've searched all over the internet for this but couldn't find a decent solution for logging in through the prestashop webservice. The script i've created for logging in is shown below.

```
require_once('./PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

/**
 * get information from PrestaShop
 */

$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($url, $key, $debug);

$COOKIE_KEY = '_key';
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$password = md5('_key' . $_REQUEST['password']);

// The database hash for testing (random)
$passwordString = '$2y$10$UsYrIFQUOr5LBUZBoqSdxODuhbToEc.2QEqfAVB1r\/fhO5EfOyO96';

$opt = array(
    'resource'       => 'customers',
    'filter[email]'  => '['.$email.']',
    'display' => '[email,lastname,firstname, passwd]'
);

$result = ($webService->get( $opt ));

$json = json_encode($result);


$optUser = array(
    'resource'       => 'customers',
    'filter[email]'  => '['.$email.']',
    'display' => '[email,lastname,firstname,passwd]'
);

$resultUser = ($webService->get( $optUser ));

$userResult = json_encode($resultUser);

// Check the email
function hasEmail($string, $email)
{
    return strpos($string, $email) !== false;
}

// Check the Password
function hasPassword($string, $password)
{
    return strpos($string, $password) !== false;
}

if(hasEmail($userResult, $email) == true and hasPassword($userResult, $password) == true)  {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'] = $email;
    // redirect is kut.
    echo
        '<html>
         <head>
           <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
         </head>
         </html>';
} else {
// Here, we use single quotes for PHP and double quotes for JavaScript
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Wrong username or password!")';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Small second question: How would i be able to run a -> go to url in the success statement, Currently the `echo "<script></script>";` isn't working and since the `header()` can't be used i'm having some trouble redirecting on succes.

As always, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/313908-webservice-login-via-a-webservice/ or this https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/586951-webservice-login-customer-prestashop-17/ could help out. Also have a look at the class Tools.php in the classes folder and search for encrypt or hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate the cookie key prestashop uses:

```
array('_COOKIE_KEY_', Tools::passwdGen(56)),
array('_COOKIE_IV_', Tools::passwdGen(8)),
```

So that cookie key is different everytime. In order to verify if the password is good you should get existing password from database and compare with your user-submitted password:

```
//CHECK IF THE GIVEN EMAIL MATCHES A ROW IN OUR LEGACY TABLE AND RETRIEVES THE LEGACY PASSWORD
$resultZC = Db::getInstance()->getRow('
SELECT `password`
FROM `zc_legacy_passwords`
WHERE `email` = \''.pSQL($email).'\'
AND `updated` = 0');

 if (!$resultZC)
return false; //<- EMAIL NOT FOUND IN NONE OF THE TABLES, SO IT IS AN INVALID LOGIN

//ENCRYPTS THE GIVEN PASSWORD IN ZEN-CART / OSCOMMERCE FORMAT
$salt = substr($resultZC['password'], strrpos($resultZC['password'],':')+1, 2);
$ZCpassword = md5($salt . $passwd) . ':' . $salt;

if ($ZCpassword != $resultZC['password'])
return false; //<- WRONG ZEN-CART/OSCOMMERCE PASSWORD GIVEN
```

This is the part that you're asking for:

```
//ENCRYPTS THE GIVEN PASSWORD IN ZEN-CART / OSCOMMERCE FORMAT
$salt = substr($resultZC['password'], strrpos($resultZC['password'],':')+1, 2);
$ZCpassword = md5($salt . $passwd) . ':' . $salt;
```

where **$resultZC['password']** is the password stored in the database and, **$passwd** is your password

Comment: due to the fact that the prestashop version is 1.7 >= There is a new update wich sets the old password encryption to invalid. The new technique to password encryption / decryption is crypto from symfony, so i'll update my question or ask a new one in time if i can't figure out the new way of password decryption / comparing

Answer (score 1):

if PrestaShop version is 1.6, the function to encrypt customer passwords is Tools::encrypt($passwd). This method just do this:

```
return md5(_COOKIE_KEY_.$passwd);
```

So knowing the _COOKIE_KEY_ you must be able to generate the hash.
_COOKIER_KEY_ is defined in config/settings.inc.php

If PrestaShop version is 1.7, Tools is not used and maybe md5(_COOKIE_KEY_.$passwd) will not match. It is used crypto from Symfony.

However, I guess PrestaShop webservice must have something to check users, in Customer class there is the method getByEmail(...) that is used in both 1.6 and 1.7 versions.

Regards.

Comment: The prestashop version is 1.7 (up to date). And due to the earlier 1.6 version i already tried the `return md5(_COOKIE_KEY_.$passwd);` As expected didn't work. I will take a look at your advise about crypto!

Comment: Hi, I've done an automated login task for PrestaShop 1.7.2.2 and md5(_COOKIE_KEY_.$passwd) has work for me. So, look for another reason in your code to fail check password, maybe there is something more.

Comment: Could you show me the task you've created with the md5 function to check the input password?

Comment: It's a different situation from yours, but they are related, so I tell you what I do. First, I'm managing employees, not customers, but I guess passwords work the same way in both cases. I update passwd directly in database for an employee, setting it as md5(COOKIE_KEY.$passwd). Then, I visit backend login url using email and $passwd. PrestaShop successfully authenticates me as that employee, so that's why I think PrestaShop 1.7 (still) uses md5(COOKIE_KEY.$passwd) to encrypt passwords.

Comment: So using md5(cookie_key.$theinputpassword) should return the password hash? Or should i use password_verify() as function? And i presume it is all in php